# asp.net waiting animation without using UpdateProgress

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updateprogress

I have an aspx page in which there are some fileUPload controls and a button.

I want an animation to be shown to the user after clicking the button so that the user is being entertained while processing posted files, ***BUT*** I do **not** want to use an `UpdatePanel` and `UpdateProgress` controls, since the update panel does not let me access the posted files of my fileupload controls.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncFileUpload control provides a `TrobberID` property which used for specifying an control that is shown while file is uploading.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) is a complete example of Async FileUpload. Use `ThrobberID="myThrobber"` for this purpose.